# Error when create django application on pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, archlinux

Few days ago I installed pycharm, then I create Django project and got error at step general...: `Error creating Django application...`

[image]

I use:

```
- python 3.8
- pycharm 2022.1.3 (pro version)
- archlinux (kernel 5.15.53-1-lts)
- i3 version 4.20
- xorg-server version 21.1.3
```

Any idea to fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have same config, only dw is bspwm. I only added `export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1` on zshrc or bashrc it working fine.

Comment: i tried but not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).